# CSS grid not aligning in Y-axis

Tags: html, css

It's a small problem but I don't get it. I am just trying to align the text in y-axis, but it only goes a little distance down when I put align-self : end or center. Container is the main grid, which contains the *col* div (columns) which has the *con* div (content) which contains the text inside the *box* div

CSS

```
.container{

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,22.45em);
  grid-template-rows: 48rem;
  grid-template-areas:
  "colone coltwo colthr colfour";
  /*text-align: center;*/

}
.con{
  /*
  padding-left: 0.5rem auto;
  padding-right: 0.5rem auto;
  padding-top: 0.5rem auto;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem auto;*/
  display: grid;
  grid-area: con;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;

  position: relative;
}
.col{
  border-right: 0.005rem solid white;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 16rem;
  grid-template-areas: "con";
  color: grey;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box{
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: end;
}
```

here is the codepen link : https://codepen.io/aronnora/project/editor/DkyrVM

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to put the content inside its own container and then give it some properties of its own

```
.center-Container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

or a simpler way to just add a `padding-top: 40%;` to your existing content

Comment: for some reason padding doesn't work and I'd like to work with only grid displays. I got my answer from another user though so don't worry about it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

So I went through your CSS. I inspected the elements and found out that the child element with class `.con` have the default height and is also not inheriting the parent's height because you haven't set height to parent which is not necessary since you are using the `grid-template-rows: 48em`.

So I would suggest you to set height of `.con`
for eg.

```
.con {
  height: 48em;
}
```

I hope this solves your query.

Comment: thank you so much I understood the problem and this works perfect

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Kindly accept the answer so that others will know too